# Move-Item doesn't move files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move a bunch of files in child directories into the parent directory. I have verified that the individual search works and that my concatenations are correct. However, the Move-Item does.. nothing.

I can't figure out why.

```
Get-ChildItem $pwd -name -recurse *.docx | foreach{ Move-Item (Join-Path . $_) .}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: Updated with the solution specific to my problem based on J.Drexler's explanation/answer.

```
Get-ChildItem $pwd -name -recurse *.docx | Move-Item -Destination .
```

Comment: Add `-whatif` or `-verbose` to your Move-Item command to see what is going on.

Comment: `Move-Item $_.FullName .\ `

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen:, the output of Get-ChildItem is a string. So $_.FullName will not work.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: @abjbhat sorry, didn't notice the `-Name` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done like this :

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.docx"  | move-item -Destination  (split-path $path -Parent )
```

Note: You don't need a "foreach" after a "|".
If you use "|" after a listing-command, its the same like:

```
$items = GetList $path
foreach($item in $items){ DoSomething $item }
```

this is same as:

```
GetList $path | DoSomething
```

Comment: Thanks! So, argument 1 is each item of the result of the expression to the left. Understood.